# assign queue object to object.owner with Apex

Tags: apex, custom-object, sobject

Hi note I am new to Apex / Salesforce.

Run down is at a specific instance I wish to create a new object but I wish to assign the Owner to a custom Queue I have prepared.

Probably a simple fix just don't know my way around the objects well enough currently, any help will be appreciated.
the listed i tried but dont work...

Code is edited and working, thank you

```
            queuesobject que = [Select Queue.Id From QueueSObject where Queue.Name = 'myvar' limit 1];
            newClaim.Ownerid = que.Queueid;
            //newClaim.Owner = que.QueueId;
            //newClaim.Owner = que;
            //newClaim.Owner = que.id;
            //newClaim.Owner = que.Queue.ID;
            addClaim.add(newClaim);
            insert addClaim;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should get thru with this

```
newClaim.OwnerId = que.Id;
```

Owner refers to the object and OwnerId refers to the Id field..

Also, when you query you don't need to specify object name in front of the fields.. your query can be like this

```
Select Id From QueueSObject where Name = 'myvar' limit 1
```

Comment: Thx it worked.... such a silly error. have to wait 8 minutes  to accept ure answer.

Comment: Thanks a mill, still learning my way through some of the object handling in apex. had some difficulty with RecordType as well but sorted that one out. Will catch the hang of it eventually. Thanks for clarity on Query as well.. think through my trial and error I over complicated it :).

Comment: Might be changed but it does not work for me. This works:   
SELECT id, queue.name, queue.email FROM QueueSObject WHERE queue.name = 'queue label not name' limit 1